# Gradient color effect on UIView in iOS 10 Swift 2.3 Xcode 8

Tags: ios10, xcode8, linear-gradients, swift2

I am trying to achieve a gradient color on a `UIView` or button with two color black which fades out to clear color or white color (please see image).

I have tried using different combinations of white color, clear color; experimenting with alpha as well. I have also set the `locations` property as can be seen in below code but I am not able to achieve desired results.

Can anyone tell me where I am wrong. :)

```
       let colorClear = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    let colorLeft =  UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 0.9).CGColor
    let colorRight = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [colorLeft, colorRight]
    gradientLayer.locations = [ 0.1, 0.9]
    gradientLayer.frame = self.createAccountView.bounds
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x:1.0, y:0.5)
    createAccountView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    createAccountView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

The desired result is the one in which black color transitions to a faded one.

I have already tried setting both colors as black and the color1 with an alpha. 
I have already tried commenting `locations` property.
[image: desired results][image]

Answer (score 0):

you should set gradientLayer.frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews().

Like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    let colorClear = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
let colorLeft =  UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 0.9).CGColor
let colorRight = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

    self.gradientLayer.colors = [colorLeft, colorRight]
    self.gradientLayer.locations = [ 0.1, 0.9]
    self.gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:0.5)
    self.gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x:1.0, y:0.5)
    createAccountView.layer.addSublayer(self.gradientLayer)
    createAccountView.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

override viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubViews()
    self.gradientLayer.frame = self.createAccountView.bounds
}
```